# El numero de variables no coinciden con tokens

Tags: php, mysql

He empezado a programar por diversión hace poco y no tengo mucha idea.
Mi problema es que dice que el numero de variables no coincide con el numero de tokens pero estoy venga a revisar y no me he saltado ninguno y tampoco he repetido ninguno.
La base de datos se llama **scelb**, la tabla es **usuario**, en la tabla también tengo la fila **id** pero esta puesta como auto incrementable así que no tengo que poner esa variable ¿No?.

El error es:

"***Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens***"

El código es:

```
<?php

class usuario {

    public static function registrar_usuario() {
        $nombreServidor = "localhost";
        $usuario = "root";
        $password = "";

        try {

            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$nombreServidor;dbname=scelb", $usuario, $password);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $nombre_usuario = $_POST['nombre_usuario'];
            $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
            $primer_apellido = $_POST['primer_apellido'];
            $segundo_apellido = $_POST['segundo_apellido'];
            $fecha_nacimiento = $_POST['fecha_nacimiento'];
            $edad = calcular_edad($_POST['fecha_nacimiento']);
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['password1'];
            $fecha_registro = date("Y-m-d");
            $avatar = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']));
            $rol = "usuario";
            $faltas = 0;
            $baneado = 0;

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre_usuario, nombre, primer_apellido, segundo_apellido, fecha_nacimiento, edad, email, password, fecha_registro, avatar, rol, faltas, baneado)VALUES (':nombre_usuario', ':nombre', ':primer_apellido', ':segundo_apellido', ':fecha_nacimiento', ':edad, ':email', ':password', ':fecha_registro', ':avatar', ':rol', ':faltas', ':baneado')");

            $stmt->bindParam(':nombre_usuario', $nombre_usuario);
            $stmt->bindParam(':nombre', $nombre);
            $stmt->bindParam(':primer_apellido', $primer_apellido);
            $stmt->bindParam(':segundo_apellido', $segundo_apellido);
            $stmt->bindParam(':fecha_nacimiento', $fecha_nacimiento);
            $stmt->bindParam(':edad', $edad);
            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
            $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
            $stmt->bindParam(':fecha_registro', $fecha_registro);
            $stmt->bindParam(':avatar', $avatar);
            $stmt->bindParam(':rol', $rol);
            $stmt->bindParam(':faltas', $faltas);
            $stmt->bindParam(':baneado', $baneado);
            $stmt->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

        $conn = null;
    }

}
```

[image: La tabla]

Comment: El primer error es que estás tratando de enlazar las variables antes de crearlas, por favor soluciona eso y modifica la pregunta.

Comment: @Triby ya lo he modificado, pero me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: @Triby, gracias por tu ayuda, pero ya lo he conseguido arreglar. El problema era que me faltaba una ' en ':edad' tenia puesto ':edad